# Codeception route assertion failure

Tags: php, laravel-4, functional-testing, laravel-routing, codeception

First attempt at codeception.

Using Laravel I have this route

```
Route::get('/', ['as'=>'home', 'uses'=>'HomeController@index']);
```

And then have a redirect issued from a method like so:

```
return Redirect::route('home');
```

Now this test fails

```
$i->seeCurrentRouteIs('home');
```

with

```
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'/'
+''
```

Comment: Try `Route::get('', ...)`

Comment: Tried. No luck, getting the same issue.

Comment: I am currently using this workaround `$i->seeCurrentUrlEquals('');`

Comment: Post it as an answer then.